# XCode 4.2 and SDK 4.3 have Custom button font issue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I'm using custom button (label button). Works fine on SDK 5.0 but when I simulate to SDK 4.3 it gives me bigger font. Does anyone know what would be the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, fonts have changed beetween SDK4.3 and SDK5. SDK4.3 default fonts where bolder/bigger that the one set by default in SDK5. What is the reason of this... I don't know. You should set yourself the wanted font instead of using the default system one to have a similar rendering in both case.

Comment: I was using an image instead. Thank you for the response.